# In the listview control i need to display an an message telling an number of records found

Tags: asp.net

i have an datatable  with  23  records so now the Count of the table is  "23"
i need  to  display  this message in listview  control.

so where  should i write this message telling **number  of records in  23**

which template  should i  use  here to achive this one
 do we have  any builtin option  for this

thank  you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use InsertItemTemplate to be a workaround as a footer row to display summary:

http://blog.evonet.com.au/post/2008/08/17/Inserting-a-new-record-from-the-Listviews-footer.aspx

Or you can set a footer row in LayoutTemplate with  tag:

http://basgun.wordpress.com/2008/01/01/listview-freeze-lock-header-footer-with-css/

Thanks,

Comment: First link in answer is dead - *"This site can’t be reached / blog.evonet.com.au’s server DNS address could not be found"*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
DataTable mytable = new DataTable();
int table_count = mytable.count;
mylistview.items.Add("number of records is: "+ table_count.ToString());
```